# Where is the TV out option on iPhones using iOS 5?

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 4 running iOS 5 and an Apple Composite AV Cable. I cannot find the TV Out option that used to be under the dearly departed 'iPod' settings menu that is now gone for iOS 5. This is quite perplexing because I have been watching video off of this iPhone and operating system as recently as a week ago, on a different television, and now I cannot figure it out.

Where is the TV out option? Can I suddenly not watch videos?

EDIT: I have seen that it is supposed to magically appeared when it is plugged into the dock, under "Settings > General", but I have it plugged into the cable and nothing is happening. I don't have a "dock," I just have the composite cable.

Comment: And it still does not appear when the other end of the cable is plugged into the TV (or monitor) and the TV is turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cable has a faulty connection and takes effort to connect to the iPhone. The TV Out option wasn't appearing because the cable wasn't connecting to the iPhone unless I pushed it in, held it, and then gently left it alone. When that happens, the TV Out option appears.